# I wanted to draw pie chart and bar chart into my php website

Tags: php, jquery

I wanted to draw pie chart and bar chart into my php website. so what are the best ways to draw chart?

Comment: make an effort and research this on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a javascript charting library such as flot or jqplot. Another easy way is to use google visualization.

- https://github.com/aaronjorbin/flot-examples/blob/master/index.php
- http://www.jqplot.com/tests/
- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference

There are many more libraries than this - do your research and choose the one that fits your needs.

Comment: i use google charts it works fine in my local server.but when i upload on live server then it is visible only once means blinking once and then disappear. please help me

Comment: Please ask a new question with specifics. If you can, I would even suggest posting the code and asking in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.